# Prevent NSMenu from creating multiple instances of same NSWindow when clicked

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nsmenu

I have a simple Cocoa Application that launches a NSWindow when an NSMenu item is clicked.  I am initiating the window via a segue.  The problem is when I click the menu item multiple times it keeps creating new windows instead of bringing the existing window to the foreground.  How can I prevent this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your `NSMeniItem`-action.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Select destination window controller
2. Click attribute inspector and select under Presentation "Single" instead of "Multiple"

[image: Single window instance]

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple.

Comment: Is there a way this can be achieved programatically?

Comment: check presentedViewControllers property

Comment: What should I do if I don't use segue ? 
Just programmatically init window after pressing on context menu button

Comment: This case means you do memory management yourself -> you know if you created it before. Your question is more like how to create window with viewcontroller.

Answer (score 5):

If you have your Window without using Storyboard, lets say you created separate `.xib` and ViewController to this `.xib`, you could use the following approach:

Add to your class:

```
lazy var testViewcontroller = TestViewController(nibName: "TestWindow", bundle: nil)
lazy var testWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: testViewcontroller)
```

Then, add this to the method where you invoke the window:

```
testWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true) // will help your window to open on top of others
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just why is NSApp.activate necessary? PS: the app is already active.

Comment: @MarekH Thanks. If you want your window to open on top of others and not be lost behind others - then yes. In my case, I have just the NSStatuItem app  -> when you click on it there is a list of NSMenuItems, and then by clicking a specific MenuItem window opens and I don't want this window to be lost somewhere behind others (especially when it's a small window. :)

Comment: I can confirm NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true) is required for menubar apps as they have different activation policy. However, I think those commands should be reordered.